# docker-compose dynamic extra_hosts to another service

Tags: docker-compose

I need to set up a docker-compose with fake hosts.  I do not want to hardcode an IP address, as I suspect it will not be consistent between runs.  How do I replace "172.20.0.2" with the dynamic internal IP address of the "server" service?

To test the code below:

- run `docker-compose up server`
- use `docker inspect` to find the `IPAddress` of the container and update the IP below
- run `docker-compose run tester`
- Expected: show nginx default page instead of google's

```yaml
version: '3'
services:

  server:
    image: nginx:latest
    networks:
      - no_internet

  tester:
    image: quay.io/curl/curl:latest
    networks:
      - no_internet
    command: -sS google.com
    extra_hosts:
      - "google.com:172.20.0.2"   ## <--  the internal IP of the "server" service

networks:
  no_internet:
    internal: true
```